# Java Calculator program issue

Tags: java, loops, math, switch-statement, double

I am trying to develop a calculator program that inputs an arithmetic expression of the form `number operator number =` and computes the result of the expression. The expression will be evaluated from left to right not considering regular operator precedence. For example, the expression `14 - 5 * 3 =` will produce `27.0`. The value `=` displays the final result and terminates the program.

I've been trying to fix this for a couple of days now, but it outputs the wrong answer whenever I enter an expression with more than two numbers. For instance, `2.8 + 2 - 9.5` should equal `-4.7` but the program outputs `-6.7`. Any idea why that is the case?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

    // Compute an arithmetic expression 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Declare the identifiers
        final String END = "=";
        String input;
        double num1 = 0;
        double num2 = 0;
        char operator = 0;
        
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter your numeric expression in the following form: ");
        System.out.println("number operator number operator number = ");
        System.out.println("Leave a blank space after each number or operator.");
        System.out.println("Example: 3.5 * 3 - 5 / 2.5 =");

        // Input the first item
        System.out.print("> ");
        input = scnr.next();
        
        // Process the first item and input and process the rest of the items 
        while (!input.equals(END)){
            switch (input){
                case "+":               
                    operator = '+';
                    System.out.println("> Operator is: " + operator);
                    break;
                case "-":               
                    operator = '-';
                    System.out.println("> Operator is: " + operator);
                    break;
                case "*": 
                    operator = '*';
                    System.out.println("> Operator is: " + operator);
                    break;
                case "/": 
                    operator = '/';
                    System.out.println("> Operator is: " + operator);
                    break;                  
                default: // a number was entered
                    if (num1 == 0) {
                        num1 = Double.parseDouble(input);
                        System.out.println("> Num1 is: " + num1);
                    }
                    else {
                        num2 = Double.parseDouble(input);
                        System.out.println("> Num2 is: " + num2);
                    }
                    
            } // end of switch
            
            if (num1 != 0 && num2 != 0) {
                
                System.out.println("Num2 before calc is " + num2);
                
                switch (operator) {
                    case '+':               
                        num2 = num1 + num2;
                        break;
                    case '-':               
                        num2 = num1 - num2;
                        break;
                    case '*': 
                        num2 = num1 * num2;
                        break;
                    case '/': 
                        num2 = num1 / num2;
                        break;
                    default:
                }
            }
            input = scnr.next();
            
        } // end of while-loop
        
        // Display the answer
        System.out.println("> Answer is: " + num2);
        
        
        
        System.out.println("Have a nice day!");
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Just go through your code and ask yourself what values each variable will have after each step. Or run it under a debugger. In particular, after "2.8 + 2" has been input, and added up, where does the total go, and where will the next number (9.5) go, and what will be the operands to the subtraction?

Comment: Also note: even for your reduced requirements, you aren't doing proper parsing. What if the user enters `0 + 1` ... then your code will fail, because num1 turns 0, and you use that as **marker** that tells you that you still waiting for the first operand. The real answer might be: accept that this is more complicated than you thought, and then decide whether you want to REALLY understand and solve this stuff. If so, turn to a good tutorial, like https://blog.mbedded.ninja/programming/algorithms-and-data-structures/how-to-parse-mathematical-expressions/

Comment: That link lists the key terms that matter for you, and that you then can research one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make it work, try to:

- in your 2nd switch statement, change `num2 = num1 + num2;` into `num1 = num1 + num2;`. Do this for all cases;
- I added an `isOperator` boolean to skip computing the operation if input is an operator.

Full code below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

    // Compute an arithmetic expression 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Declare the identifiers
        final String END = "=";
        String input;
        double num1 = 0;
        double num2 = 0;
        char operator = 0;
        boolean isOperator;
        
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter your numeric expression in the following form: ");
        System.out.println("number operator number operator number = ");
        System.out.println("Leave a blank space after each number or operator.");
        System.out.println("Example: 3.5 * 3 - 5 / 2.5 =");

        // Input the first item
        System.out.print("> ");
        input = scnr.next();
        
        // Process the first item and input and process the rest of the items 
        while (!input.equals(END)){
            isOperator = true;
            switch (input){
                case "+":               
                    operator = '+';
                    System.out.println("> Operator is: " + operator);
                    break;
                case "-":               
                    operator = '-';
                    System.out.println("> Operator is: " + operator);
                    break;
                case "*": 
                    operator = '*';
                    System.out.println("> Operator is: " + operator);
                    break;
                case "/": 
                    operator = '/';
                    System.out.println("> Operator is: " + operator);
                    break;                  
                default: // a number was entered
                    isOperator = false;
                    if (num1 == 0) {
                        num1 = Double.parseDouble(input);
                        System.out.println("> Num1 is: " + num1);
                    }
                    else {
                        num2 = Double.parseDouble(input);
                        System.out.println("> Num2 is: " + num2);
                    }
                    
            } // end of switch
            
            // do not compute the operation if the input is an operator and num1,num2 != 0
            if (num1 != 0 && num2 != 0 && !isOperator) {
                
                System.out.println("Num2 before calc is " + num2);
                
                switch (operator) {
                    case '+':               
                        num1 = num1 + num2;
                        break;
                    case '-':               
                        num1 = num1 - num2;
                        break;
                    case '*': 
                        num1 = num1 * num2;
                        break;
                    case '/': 
                        num1 = num1 / num2;
                        break;
                    default:
                }
            }
            input = scnr.next();
            
        } // end of while-loop
        
        // Display the answer
        System.out.println("> Answer is: " + num1);
        
        
        
        System.out.println("Have a nice day!");
        
    }
}
```

**Edit:** As mentioned in the comments, the code does not treat the cases when the user inputs `0`. Below, I removed the `if(num1 == 0)` and `if (num1 != 0 && num2 != 0)` conditions:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

    // Compute an arithmetic expression 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Declare the identifiers
        final String END = "=";
        String input;
        double result = 0;
        double num = 0;
        char operator = 0;
        boolean isOperator;
        
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter your numeric expression in the following form: ");
        System.out.println("number operator number operator number = ");
        System.out.println("Leave a blank space after each number or operator.");
        System.out.println("Example: 3.5 * 3 - 5 / 2.5 =");

        // Input the first item
        System.out.print("> ");
        input = scnr.next();
        
        // Process the first item and input and process the rest of the items 
        while (!input.equals(END)){
            isOperator = true;
            switch (input){
                case "+":               
                    operator = '+';
                    System.out.println("> Operator is: " + operator);
                    break;
                case "-":               
                    operator = '-';
                    System.out.println("> Operator is: " + operator);
                    break;
                case "*": 
                    operator = '*';
                    System.out.println("> Operator is: " + operator);
                    break;
                case "/": 
                    operator = '/';
                    System.out.println("> Operator is: " + operator);
                    break;                  
                default: // a number was entered
                    isOperator = false;
                    num = Double.parseDouble(input);
                    System.out.println("> Num is: " + num);
            } // end of switch
            
            // do not compute the operation if the input is an operator
            if (!isOperator) {
                
                System.out.println("Result before calc is " + result);
                
                switch (operator) {
                    case '+':               
                        result += num;
                        break;
                    case '-':               
                        result -= num;
                        break;
                    case '*': 
                        result *= num;
                        break;
                    case '/': 
                        result /= num;
                        break;
                    default:
                        result += num;
                }
            }
            input = scnr.next();
            
        } // end of while-loop
        
        // Display the answer
        System.out.println("> Answer is: " + result);
        
        
        
        System.out.println("Have a nice day!");
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself what happens when someone enters: `0 + 1`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, there's no need no need for the `num == 0` conditions. I added a second code snippet.

Comment: True, that works. Of course, it will break as soon as operator precedence comes in.

Answer (score 1):

I switched up your order a little bit and reset the holding variable.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     // Declare the identifiers
    final String END = "=";
    String input;
    double num1 = 0;
    double num2 = 0;
    char operator = 0;
    
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Enter your numeric expression in the following form: ");
    System.out.println("number operator number operator number = ");
    System.out.println("Leave a blank space after each number or operator.");
    System.out.println("Example: 3.5 * 3 - 5 / 2.5 =");

    // Input the first item
    System.out.print("> ");
    input = scnr.next();
    
    // Process the first item and input and process the rest of the items 
    while (!input.equals(END)){
        switch (input){
            case "+":               
                operator = '+';
                System.out.println("> Operator is: " + operator);
                break;
            case "-":               
                operator = '-';
                System.out.println("> Operator is: " + operator);
                break;
            case "*": 
                operator = '*';
                System.out.println("> Operator is: " + operator);
                break;
            case "/": 
                operator = '/';
                System.out.println("> Operator is: " + operator);
                break;                  
            default: // a number was entered
                if (num1 == 0) {
                    num1 = Double.parseDouble(input);
                    System.out.println("> Num1 is: " + num1);
                } else {
                    num2 = Double.parseDouble(input);
                    System.out.println("> Num2 is: " + num2);
                }
                
        } // end of switch
        
        if (num1 != 0 && num2 != 0) {
            
            System.out.println(String.format("Num1 : %.3f, Num2: %.3f", num1, num2));
            
            switch (operator) {
                case '+':               
                    num1 = num1 + num2;
                    num2 = 0;
                    break;
                case '-':               
                    num1 = num1 - num2;
                    num2 = 0;
                    break;
                case '*': 
                    num1 = num1 * num2;
                    num2 = 0;
                    break;
                case '/': 
                    num1 = num1 / num2;
                    num2 = 0;
                    break;
                default:
            }
        }
        input = scnr.next();
        
    } // end of while-loop
    
    // Display the answer
    System.out.println("> Answer is: " + num1);
}
```

Comment: Trick question: what happens for an input like `0 + 1`

Comment: It's his code, I just made it work the way he designed.  I would use a Double and set it to null instead of 0.